# Javascript - Script5002 - Function Expected when declaring a variable

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I've looked through quite a few answers and other places online, but I haven't found anyone that is experiencing the error in the same way that I am.

My browser just updated to IE10 and that brought this to our attention.  If I run in compatibility mode, the function seems to work just fine.  If I'm not in compatibility mode, I get an IE debugger error SCRIPT5002 - Function Expected error.

I've marked the place where I get the error with ==>.  If I take that variable out and replace the variable with the document.frames... it then references that line as the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

I inherited this code from a previous employee and have only been working with javascript for about 3 months.  Here is the code:

```
function FncSaveClient(){
//Submit Primary Client form
//Verify Data
==> var CntSumFrm = document.frames('IFrameSummary').document.all.item('DefaultFrm');
if (CntSumFrm.fireEvent('onsubmit') == true){
    CntSumFrm.submit();
}
//If Edit Mode Submit Subforms
var IntAcctNum = CntSumFrm.TxtAcctNum.value
if (IntAcctNum != 0){
    //Locations Subform
    var CntLocFrm = document.frames('IFrameLocations').document.all.item('DefaultFrm');
    if (CntLocFrm.fireEvent('onsubmit') == true){
          CntLocFrm.submit();
      }
    //Contacts Subform
    var CntContactTbl = document.frames('IFrameContacts').document.all.item('TblContactSummary')
if (CntContactTbl.rows.length-3 == 0){
        alert('You must have at least one contact per client.');
    document.all.item('BtnSubTblClientContacts').style.color='red';
    }
    //Classification Subform
    var CntClassFrm = document.frames('IFrameMarketing').document.frames('IFrameClassification').document.all.item('DefaultFrm');
    if (CntClassFrm.fireEvent('onsubmit') == true){
        CntClassFrm.submit();
      }
    //Save Client Admin
    var CntAdminFrm = document.frames('IFrameAdmin').document.all.item('DefaultFrm');
    if (CntAdminFrm.fireEvent('onsubmit') == true){
    CntAdminFrm.submit();
}
else
{
    document.all.item('BtnSubTblSalesRel').style.color='red';
}   
}

if(CntSumFrm.TxtDeleted.value == 1)
    {
    window.parent.location.href = '/Accounts/';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?  IE10 is quite different btw and adheres to more strict JavaScript usage.

Comment: If I don't have debugging enabled, the script won't submit the forms and the page does nothing.  If debugging is on, it says Function Expected (the IE debug error is SCRIPT5002 - Function Expected) and it highlights "var CntSumFrm = document.frames('IFrameSummary').document.all.item('DefaultFrm');"

Answer (score 1):

That code is full of ancient IE-specific code, that is probably not allowed anymore even by IE, unless in compatibility mode. You should look into replacing stuff like:

- `document.frames`
- `document.all`
- `.items()`

I believe the error happens because `frames` or `item` (maybe both) is not a function when IE follows the JS standards.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Java Script I wrote back in 2005 today.  An external user using IE10, which we are still back in IE8, couldn't get things to work properly.  It appears that document.all has been deprecated and is only accessibly in compatibility mode.  I removed the check I had for IE and so it now uses document.getElementById which I already had for other browsers, and it appears to work even with compatibility mode turned off.